# PyMC building & fitting model from data

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc, pymc3, bayesian-networks

*Problem Statement:*

I have a dataset and would like to learn a bayesian network from it. There are no information given for the dataset which can be used to make assumptions and create an initial model like described in the PyMC documentation. So, I would like to learn the model directly from the data without assumptions.

*Background*

I did read through the documentation of PyMC(v2 & v3) but was not able to find any method which offers me the possibility to learn a model from a given data sample. In nearly all examples I read, the author made assumptions for building a model and then fitted the model with samples.

*Related*:

jmschrei pomegranate framework offers the method [from_samples()](https://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/BayesianNetwork.html#pomegranate.BayesianNetwork.BayesianNetwork.from_samples) which consumes a complex dataframe. That is something I was looking for, however, the [sample()](https://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/BayesianNetwork.html#pomegranate.BayesianNetwork.BayesianNetwork.sample) method is not implemented. Therefore I cannot fall back on his framework.

But isnt there a similar method for pymc?

Comment: There is not  such a thing as a model free of assumptions. You always assume something, even if not explicit. Could you provide an example of what do you want do do?

Answer (score 0):

As Aloctavodia said, you cannot not be free of assumptions. I don't think it's only with PyMC, it is also the base of a scientific model. The principle of such a model is that you define parameters that you may estimate through observations. Being free of assumptions is weird. Don't you assume at least we are in our univers ? or than your data are statistically relevant ?

If you cannot propose a mathematical model. I don't think PyMC can help you. Maybe you could look towards deep learning. Hope this helps